# Why doesn't Lord Shiva have a crown?

Tags: shiva

Every deity is shown wearing a crown except Lord Shiva. He is shown as having the hairs tied (jatA).

Does anybody know why there is no crown?
Maybe any story in scriptures or a 'tAntric' reason or something else?

Comment: I think of a hint -- shri rAm is wearing crown when he is a king. But at the time he is wandering in jungle because of 'vanavAsa', he is not wearing crown (that time he is having the hairs tied). Same case regarding pAndavas. In lord shiva's case, he is not king of any kingdom (in material world), so maybe because of that he is not having a crown. This is my guess, but I don't have any supporting reference.

Comment: There is a tantric reason for it the way the Sri Rama hairs tied in vanavasa and Lord Shiva! But I dont have specific text from tantra principle saying exact reason while I can quote reference which leads to one thing and that leads to shape of hairs at head top

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT that Lord Shiva does not wear crown. Various slokas and hymns describe him as wearing crown. For example:

1. The dhyana-sloka says

> 'RatnAkalpojjvalAngam' : Whose  body is shining by the aura of different jewels.

2. The famous 'Shiva-Ashtaka-stotra' known to be composed by 'Sankaracharya' starting with 'Prabhum Isham Anisham' mentions

> sasa-lanchita-ranjita-san-MUKUTAM': Whose beautiful crown is ornamented by the Moon.

3. The 'Visvanatha-Ashtakam' composed by Vyasadeva reads

> 'shitamshu-shovita-KIRITA-birAjamAnam' : Whose crown is beautifully decorated by the Moon.

4. The 'gentle' form of Shiva is mentioned as

> wearing beautiful turban with the Moon.

According to sanskritdictionary.com, bth 'Mukuta' and 'Kirita' mean Crown :

> मुकुटम् 1 A crown, tiara, diadem; मुकुटरत्नमरीचिभिर- स्पृशत् R.9.13. [मुकुट is crescent-shaped, the किरीट is pointed and the मौलि has three points.] -2 A crest. -3 A peak, point. -Comp. -उत्पलः a crest-gem.

I have also seen many idols of Shiva of different famous temples being decorated by crowns.

I have also enclosed an image to show that the artists are also familiar with Shiva's wearing of crown.

Reference : 1. Stavakusumanjali, Udbodhan. 2.Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, RMIC, Vol. 1

[image]

Comment: 'Shiva Ashtaka' stotram which I found, mentions जटाजूट गङ्गोत्तरङ्गै र्विशालं, शिवं शङ्करं शम्भु मीशानमीडे ॥ 2॥
ref. :-
https://www.haribhoomi.com/astrology_and_spirituality/shivashtak-shiva-stotra-shiva-stuti |||| it mentions "जटाजूट"

Comment: @Vineet Shiva-Ashtaka starts with 'Prabhum isham anisham asheshagunam.. and each fourth line is : pranamami shivam shiva-kalpatarum.

Comment: where can I get it online?

Comment: @Vineet  Its on youtube sung by many. The following linkmalso has this, but it translates 'Mukuta' as 'Crest': http://hariharji.blogspot.com/2012/07/pranamami-shiva-kalpatarum.html

Answer (score 1):

In Sri Kamika Agama Purva Pada, tantravatara pathala. Srikantha Deva(Lord Shiva) reveals the 28 agamas to make thr very form of Shiva. In this scripture He mentions that the Makutagama makes the makuta or crown and other parts of His body. Hence this shows that he wears a crown.

He also is refered to be the one who wears the 'jatamukutam' the crown of jatas(dread locks).

Refrence below.

> kāmikaṁ pādayugmaṁ syādyogajaṁ gulphameva ca|   cintyaṁ pādāṅguliḥ
>   proktaḥ kāraṇaṁ jaṅghikā bhavet|| 93   ajitaṁ jānudeśaṁ syād
>   dīptemūrupradeśakam|   sūkṣmaṁ tu guhyamevaṁ syātsahasraṁ
>   kaṭideśakam|| 94   aṁśumān syāt pṛṣṭhatalaṁ suprabhedaṁ tu nābhikam|
>   vijayaṁ kukṣideśaṁ syān niśvāsaṁ hṛdayaṁ bhavet|| 95   svāyaṁbhuvaṁ
>   stanau dvau tu analaṁ netrameva ca|   vīraṁ kaṇṭhapradeśastu rauravaṁ
>   śrotrameva ca|| 96   makuṭaṁ mākuṭaṁ tantraṁ aṅgapratyaṅgameva ca|
>   bāhū tu vimalaṁ proktaṁ candrajñānaṁ urassthalam|| 97   bimbatantraṁ
>   suvadanaṁ prodgītaṁ rasanā bhavet|   lalitaṁ syātkapolaṁ tu siddhaṁ
>   caiva lalāṭakam|| 98   santānaṁ kuṇḍalaṁ vidyāccharvoktaṁ upavītakam| 
>   pārameśāna hāraṁ tu kiraṇaṁ ratnabhūṣaṇam|| 99   vātulaṁ vasanaṁ
>   proktaṁ śivadharma tripuṇḍrake|   kalpañcaiva tu saṁyoge
>   śivadharmānulepane|| 100   bimbaṁ puṣpe ca mālye ca siddhāntena
>   niveditam|   tantrātmaka śarīreṇa mantramūrtimayena tu|| 101
>   eteṣāmupabhedaiśca sādākhyaṁ mūrtimat sthitam|
>
> Lord Siva appears in a form constituted of these Agamas. In this form,
>   the Kamika is present ) as His two feet. Yogaja- ankle; Cintya –
>   fingers of the feet; Karana – shank; Ajita – knees;  Dipta – thigh
>   regions; Sukshma – the loins; Sahasra – hip region; Amsuman – back
>   portion;  Suprabheda – navel; Vijaya – stomach; Nisvasa – heart;
>   Svayambhuva – the breast-spots;  Anala – the eyes; Vira – neck
>   portion; Raurava – the ears; **Makuta – the crown and the main  parts
>   and sub-parts of the body;** Vimala – the shoulders; Candrajnana – the
>   chest region;  Bimba – the well-formed face; Prodgita – tongue; Lalita
>   – the cheek; Siddha – the fore-head;  Santana – the ear rings;Sarvokta
>   – the sacred thread; Paramesvara – ornamental chain; Kirana- the 
>   ornaments made of gems; Vatula – the attire; all the auspicious deeds
>   recommended in these  Agamas – the three stripes of holy ash; all the
>   specific preparations such as arghya-water and  others – the
>   waist-belt and such other items needed for the body; all the
>   directions related to the  worship of Siva – the perfumed unguents;
>   all the vereses related to meditation of form(dhyana)  denote the
>   various flowers and garlands; the principles set forth in the
>   knowledge-section  (jnana pada) – the eatables to be offered to Him.

Comment: Note that promoting any peetha or personality may be considered spam. Take a look at [expected behavior](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Visit [help] for more information.

Comment: Your answer states that 'shiva' wears 'jatAmukuta'. That is already known. My question starts from this point. Why 'jatA' or 'jatAmukuta'? I have clearly asked this without any ambiguity.

Comment: This does not answer the question.Jatamukuta is NOT crown.What the other mentioned sloka says is also indirect.

Comment: Also, there is no word 'Makuta' in sanskrit that means crown.There is MUKUTA of course.

Answer (score -1):

Lord Shiva is a Bairagi. He has abandoned everything. He has achieved a Nirvikalpa Samadhi. His gaze is always focused on Parmatma. which is His true nature.It is said that his house is crematorium itself.
So being a supreme Bairagi , Lord Shiva does not wear a crown.

Edit: 
Sharing link of the song that calls Shiva as Bairagi..
Link : https://youtu.be/78n1ku39kaY

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, answer needs to be supported by authentic source else it might be marked as 'primarily opinion based'. Pl. see this https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions

Comment: @Vineet I have attached the link to the source... have a look...

Comment: @Deepeshkumar Youtube isn't considered valid source here. Visit [faq](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/277) and [preferable sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/816/277).

Comment: I am trying to find the good source... need some time